# Is it possible to "Lock" a window in place?

Tags: compiz

With the default Ubuntu Oneiric UI is it possible to lock a window in place?  That is to say, once the window is positioned I would like to press a designated "Lock" key or select a designated "Lock Window" menu item from some menu which causes the window to become unmovable, un-resizable and un-closable until I un-check a menu item.

If this is not possible with the default window manager, is there a package I can install that will add this feature?   If there isn't, what is the most common alternative window manager that offers this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is as close as you'll get for that kind of control of windows.
[Devilspie and gDevilspie](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/how-to-start-applications-minimized.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Kubuntu on Lubuntu due to I wanted both applicatiosn that they came together.

1. By opening a window eg. a folder,
2. on its top bar, right click
3. ---> more actions
4. ---> configure special windows settings
5. A lot of options!!! [image: see pic]

I dont know if in ubuntu desktop something like this exists or it can be installed as add on.